# Setting SPF record on Amazon Route 53 with cli53 tool

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, amazon-route53, amazon-ses

My domain is already with Amazon [Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) and I can use the [cli53](https://github.com/barnybug/cli53) command line tool quite happily to maintain it.

We are moving to use Amazon [SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) and I would like to add an SPF record to the domain, as per the [docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/)... we have no prior existing record. This is just for automated emails to customers, not internal user accounts.

I can't for the life of me figure out what the command line is to do this, can anyone provide an example?

```
$ cli53 rrcreate -x 3600 -r --wait mydomain.com '' 'SPF' 'v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ?all'

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
boto.route53.exception.DNSServerError: DNSServerError: 400 Bad Request
...
  
    Sender
    InvalidChangeBatch
    Invalid Resource Record: FATAL problem: InvalidTXTRDATA encountered at v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ?all
```

Comment: Does `cli53 rrcreate -x 3600 -r --wait mydomain.com '' 'SPF' '"v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ?all"'` work?

Comment: Genius! That worked! Why don't you post it as a proper response and I'll mark you as the correct answer! Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@ceejayoz's comment has the answer, which is to add double quotes around the TXT record data.

```
cli53 rrcreate -x 3600 -r --wait mydomain.com '' 'SPF' '"v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ?all"'
```